# angular locker localstorage getting removed after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

When I refresh my application, local storage getting removed automatically.
Here am using angular-locker, even I didn't use locker.empty() anywhere in project. [image]

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Thanks, As per company policy, Am not able to share my code.

Comment: I didn't asked your application code. SOF wants only the error/not working part

Comment: May be  localStorage.clear(); there...

Answer (score 2):

Browser never resets your local storage. It must be hiding the data or There must be some script going on in your code that is doing this.

> Like localStorage.clear();

Try closing and opening developers tools tab (f12 / ctrl+shift+i), My browser hides localstorage when I refresh the page but when I close and reopen developers tools tab, I am able to see localstorage data again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your local storage is removed , it is just invisible..
just try to print your data stored in local storage.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("your key"));
```

and you will get result.

it is a bug , if you want to check then just try to clear the storage and keep the **Application** tag open in **developer option**, you will see it will be there and once you reload it will disappear but data will be there..